# Create a lookup field that is text instead of a drop-down (or similar)?

Tags: lookup-column

In SharePoint, I have a list (staff) and a document library and have successfully made a custom lookup column/field from the document library pointing to the staff list (staff id column).

This works ok, I now see a drop down showing me the staff id's, but what I would really like to do is have a text box (or some similar functionality) that will allow me to type part of a staff id, or even better a staff name to link to a staff record.

I have searched, but not found anything like this. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to do some custom javascript to accomplish this. Getting all the items in the lookup field and adding a text box with autocomplete for only those items.

Also, you'd need to validate the text box so users could only submit when a value matches that item. Afterwards populating the lookup field based on the text field.

Answer (score 1):

I used the [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) JS library to make the dropdown searchable.

I used it along with [PullInformationFromConncectedList.js](http://spjsblog.com/2010/02/26/display-information-from-another-list-based-on-a-lookup-column-connection/) to display additional details on selecting a lookup value which in your case will display staff name when you search based on id.